# Fetch data from MySQL database in Nuxt.js 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

I'm new to Nuxt.js 3 and I'm currently experimenting with displaying data from my database.

The database is a MySQL database, and has one table called 'test'. The table has four columns:

1. id
2. name
3. lastName
4. age

First I download this to my project: npm install @nuxtjs/axios mysql

I have created a file 'mysql.js' in the 'plugins' folder, with the code as written below:

```
import mysql from 'mysql'

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'myhost',
    user: 'myusername',
    password: 'mypassword',
    database: 'mydatabase',
})

connection.connect()

export default (context, inject) => {
    inject('mysql', connection)
}
```

I have created a new page in the 'pages' folder called 'index.vue' which consists of this code:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <h1>Test Table Data</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id">
            <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.age }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
  data() {
    return {
      rows: [],
    }
  },
  async asyncData({ $mysql }) {
    const rows = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $mysql.query('SELECT * FROM test', (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error)
        } else {
          resolve(results)
        }
      })
    })

    return {
      rows,
    }
  },
}
  </script>
```

When I start the server I get this error message.

> [warn] [nuxt] You are using a plugin with legacy Nuxt 2 format (context, inject) which is likely to be broken. In the future they will be ignored: (context, inject) => {
> inject('mysql', connection)
> }

I've tried a lot of different ways, but this solution is the one I get the fewest errors on...

Hope someone can give a hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since you use Nuxt 3, not 2, you want to use the way a plugin is done in Nuxt 3.

[Documentation for this](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#plugins-directory)

You probably want to have something like this:

```
import mysql from 'mysql'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {

  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'myhost',
      user: 'myusername',
      password: 'mypassword',
      database: 'mydatabase',
  })
  connection.connect()

  return {
    provide: {
      mysql: connection
    }
  }
})
```

[Documentation for the above code](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#automatically-providing-helpers)

Additionally, you want to use Nuxt 3  in your components, just like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const { $mysql } = useNuxtApp()

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try download this:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/mysql
```